# Lie-Algebra Bundle and Wigner-Inönü Contraction

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, fiber-bundles, semisimple-lie-algebras

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354846) it is stated, that for a Lie-Algebra Bundle the isomorphism-class of the Lie-Algebra is locally constant, if the Lie-Algebra is rigid. Especially it is stated, that semisimple Lie-Algebras are rigid.

Consider now the following family of Lie-Brackets on $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined via its action on the basis elements $X_1, X_2, X_3$:

\begin{align}
[X_1, X_2]_\epsilon &= \epsilon^2 X_3 \\
[X_2, X_3]_\epsilon &= X_1 \\
[X_3, X_1]_\epsilon &= X_2
\end{align}

For all $\epsilon > 0$ this Lie-Algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, which is rigid, since it is semisimple. But as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ one gets the Lie-Algebra $\mathfrak{iso}(2)$ of the 2-dimensional Euclidean group. Further one can interpret this limit as a Wigner-Inönü Contraction of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction) for both claims) and as far as I understand, $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathfrak{iso}(2)$.

Now one could consider the smooth, trivial vector bundle $P = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^3$ and endow it with a Lie-algebra bundle structure

\begin{equation}
\theta: P \times_\mathbb{R} P \rightarrow P
\end{equation}

via

\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}: \forall X, Y \in P_\epsilon: \theta(X, Y) = [X, Y]_\epsilon
\end{equation}

where $P_\epsilon = \{\epsilon\} \times \mathbb{R}^4$ denoes the fiber of $P$ over $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$.

Here the Lie-Algebra over $0$ is given by $\mathfrak{iso}(3)$ but elsewhere it is given by $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Hence the isomorphism class is not locally constant. But $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ is rigid, and hence [[1](https://mathoverflow.net/a/354846)] says, that this situation should not occur.

Where I am missing something? I am not trained in this branch of mathematics. I ask the question here, since I want to grasp the point faster.

Comment: It is a typo, sorry! I will correct it.

Comment: It is no contradiction, since it is a *contraction* and not a nontrivial *deformation*. Rigid means there is no nontrivial deformation. Of course every Lie algebra contracts, say, to an abelian Lie algebra, so also every rigid Lie algebra.

Comment: Thanks. But then rigidity should not imply, that the isomorphism class of a Lie-Algebra Bundle is locally constant (as it is stated in the cited stack-exchange post)? Since contractions are allowed but lead out of the considered isomorphism class?

Comment: Yes, that is clear to me. But if I understand correctly, there happens a change of the isomorphism class in the fiber over $\epsilon = 0$. And this should not be allowed by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306900/lie-algebra-bundle-associated-to-a-lie-group-bundle/354846#354846 . Clearly I am missing something, but I would like to know, what exactly.